# Bootstrap: is it possible to add title block in html/css code?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a CMS theme that contains all of Bootstrap 3. Is it possible to add a title block manually in HTML/CSS? I'm not sure if that's the block's official name... it's the purple full-width block containing the text:

`CSS
Global CSS settings, fundamental HTML elements styled and enhanced with extensible classes, and an advanced grid system.`

in the following link (for example):

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

This title block is built into my theme and is available based on the design for the page I select.

But I was wondering if this block is available separately from Bootstrap, like a Navbar, panel, well, etc. component, that I can just include some HTML/CSS code and have it appear in the body of a page, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not in bootstrap but it's pretty easy to grab the style and use it anywhere:

```
.bs-docs-header {
font-size: 24px;
padding-bottom: 60px;
padding-top: 60px;
text-align: left;
}

.bs-docs-masthead, .bs-docs-header {
background-color: #6F5499;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #563D7C 0px, #6F5499 100%);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
color: #CDBFE3;
padding: 30px 15px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
```

}

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/24FNp/) jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks @alou, this works with the exception that it's not full width. I suspect this is because the template I used to place the HTML code in itself is not full width. Anyway to force the `content` div to be full width? I tried adding a `style="width:100% !important;"` to the `content` div but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: The width:100% will take all parent element width available. To get a mid-template (does this make sense?) full width style in your template, you should close container div (and any other class used in-between), have the full width element and then re-open <div class="container" ... etc. If you provide some html maybe we can looki into it

Comment: Unfortunately it's done within the CMS's theme and I'm not experienced enough to know how to get to it or manipulate it. If I can't override it somehow in the code I add, then there' probably no way for me to do it. Thanks

Comment: It can be done but you will need to check the structure of the elements, close the open wrappers and re-open them, nothing more I can say without specific html, sorry. Here's another fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/24FNp/3/

Comment: I think I see... so you just close the divs, insert the full-width code, then re-open the original divs using their original classes.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at their source, they are using a stylesheet called `docs.min.css`, they have defined the background in here. Other then that it is just a simple `<div class="container"><!--title and subtitle here-->`. So the answer is a yes and a no. You can, of course, use containers seperately from your CMS when using bootstrap, but the background will not be available unless you strip it from the getbootstrap.com source.

---

## Edit

If you see their styles, they are using this code in their `docs.min.css`:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
    .bs-docs-header h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 1;
    }
}
```

This means, when the width of your window is above 768 pixels, it gives the h1 a font-size of 60px. When you fall under it, this code is ignored and the default bootstrap font-size is being applied.

---

## Edit 2

To get a background-color behind it, don't apply the background color to the .container. wrap a div around it without a width value. The container width is not full width, so if you apply a background to it, its only behind the container that is centered.

---

## Edit 3

A simple HTML structure would be something like this (you still have to include all bootstrap styles and default html tags etc.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="bgColorDiv">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>My title</h1>
                <p>Paragraph below the title</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be more than just a container. When the browser window resizes smaller, the font size and alignment change, etc. Am I missing something? Also, I can always add the background color myself to the container, but getting it full width I'm not sure how (most likely it'll be width of body in theme).

Comment: Thanks, I've implemented, but background color doesn't extend full width. I suspect that's because the html body that my code in isn't full width. Any way to force `bgColorDiv` to be full width? I tried `style="width:100% !important;"` but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: `#bgColorDiv` should be full width as it's an block element. I obviously have no idea what your other stylesheets look like. I am pretty sure that's the issue. I assume you are doing something like this: `#bgColorDiv { background-color:red; }`

Comment: Yah, looks like the width of `bgColorDiv` is limited to the theme's width for the `Main` HTML block that it sits inside. It covers the full 12 columns created by Bootstrap. But the window's width is always somewhat larger than that.